# When clicking on an application, how does Windows determine to which HWND to send a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message?

Tags: winapi

When I click on a Window of an app - one that is **not the foreground window**, a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message is sent to one of the app's windows. 
My question is - how does Windows determine to which Window shall it sent the message? 
My initial assumption was that Windows finds the window that both:
- Contains the mouse coordinates within its region
- Has the largest Z-order

This assumption is wrong - I see a case where:
- The WM_LBUTTONDOWN message is sent to a child window
- There's a window that has a **larger Z-order** than the one received the WM_LBUTTONDOWN

Examples:

- Here, I'm clicking on the "Open Security Configuration" button:
  [image]

And the WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent to the button with HWND 0x00040678, as I expected:

[image]

- Here, I'm clicking on "Take a Tour":

[image]

But the WM_LBUTTONDOWN is sent to HWND 0x0004070A, where my assumption was that it'd sent to 0x00050678: (which is a non-transparent window, according to its style)

[image]

[image]

So, what's the real logic Windows applies?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the `_WwF` window is the `Take a Tour` text? If the `NetUIHWND` window is the one receiving the message that that is the window that the user is actually clicking on.  `NetUIHWND` is a custom-drawn control that is likely rendering the `Take a Tour` text inside of itself.  `NetUIHWND` and `DirectUIHWND` are quite common in modern Microsoft apps.

Comment: My question is - how does OS know to which window to send the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message?

Comment: Why do you want to know HOW the OS figures it out?  It KNOWS which window is under the mouse when a click occurs. The HOW is an implementation detail of the OS, and likely involves many details, not just matching coordinates and z-order. Handling clicks in transparent areas defined by either `HRGN`s or `WS_EX_LAYERED` is also a factor, for instance.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your response. I'd really like to know these implementation details, and I'd appreciate if you could elaborate on this and refer me to any relevant resource that you know about - I couldn't find any. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming mouse input isn't captured, the system posts `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to the window under the mouse cursor that's highest in the z-order and isn't transparent. Not really complicated.

Comment: @imriqwe You can check which window actually capture the mouse using [`GetCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcapture).

Comment: Mouse isn't captured, so why does `NetUIHWND` get the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and **NOT** `_WwF`? Maybe it's related to the fact that `_WwF` has the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style?

Comment: NetUIHWND is a child of FullpageUIHost, and FullpageUIHost is higher than _WwF in the z-order.

Comment: How do you know it?

Comment: From your Spy++ screenshots.